# ¿Cómo notifico al usuario la respuesta de la base de datos en FireBase?

Tags: java, firebase

Después de varias validaciones a nivel de formulario, tengo el siguiente código JAVA:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mail, p);
```

Funciona pero me gustaría saber como puedo añadir un aviso en caso de que la inserción en BD sea satisfactoria o no. He estado leyendo la documentación y no lo he entendido bien.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

debes agregar un `OnCompleteListener`

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mail, p)
    .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            // registo exitoso
        } else {
            // ocurrió un error
        }
    });
```